# Replace NonASCII Characters in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

To convert NON ASCII Characters to ASCII I used the below query

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnToCheck = CONVERT(columnToCheck USING ASCII)
 WHERE columnToCheck <> CONVERT(columnToCheck USING ASCII)
```

It replaces the NON ASCII characters into replacement characters. But is it possible to replace those Non Ascii characters to SPACES.

I tried some options, but its not working. Any suggestion.

Comment: I came here looking for the query you posted in your initial question. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Try this one

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnToCheck = REPLACE(CONVERT(columnToCheck USING ascii), '?', '')
WHERE ...
```

or

```
update tablename
set columnToCheck = replace(columnToCheck , char(146), '');
```

[**Reference**](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/14/bad-character-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: If the database is encoded UTF8 (mysql default), the first code will delete all characters with accents, which could be undesirable.