# Remove or replace '�' character in Informatica

Tags: replace, character, informatica

We have a requirement wherein we need to replace or remove '�' character (which is an unrecognizable, undefined character) present in our source. While running my workflow it runs successfully but when i check the records in target they are not committed. I get the following error in Informatica

Error executing query for record 37: 6706: The string contains an untranslatable character.

I tried functions like replace_chr, reg_replace, replace_str etc., but none seems to be working. Kindly advise on how to get rid of this. Any reply is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your source? DB or flat file?

Comment: Recently i found that our source data contains Chinese or Korean characters along with some Carriage return and Line feed characters.How do i get rid of them? Thanks in advance

Comment: Our source is DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use in your schema definitions charset=> utf8-unidode-ci

but now you can do:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnToCheck = REPLACE(CONVERT(columnToCheck USING ascii), '?', '')
WHERE ...
```

or

```
update tablename
set columnToCheck = replace(columnToCheck , char(146), '');
```

[Replace NonASCII Characters in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766939/replace-nonascii-characters-in-mysql)

Comment: I have set the code page to UTF-8 encoding and still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the special characters in an expression transformation.

```
REPLACESTR(1,Column_Name,'?',NULL)
```

**REPLACESTR** - Function
**1** - Position
 
**Column_Name** - Column name which has a special character
**?** - Special character
**NULL** - Replacing character

Comment: I have used Replace_str and Reg_replace before to get rid of � character but its not helpful for the other characters like chinese or CRLF characters. Any thoughts on that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch rows with the appropriate character set defined on your connection. What is the connection you're using, ODBC or native? What's the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Special characters are a  challenge and having checked the informatica network I can see there is a kludge involving replace_str setting first a variable to the string with all non special characters first and then using the resulting variable in a replace_str so that the final value has only the allowed characters  https://network.informatica.com/thread/20642 (awesome workaround by nico so long as you can positively identify every character that should be allowed) ...

As an alternate kludge I would also attempt something using an xml transformation somewhere within the mapping as informatica conveniently converts special characters to encoded (decimal or hex I cant remember) values... so long as you can live with these encoded values appearing in your target text you should be fine ( and build some extra space into your strings to accommodate any bloatage from the extra characters